# pandas join operation (very large data)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with around 5 million rows. The columns represent a sort of key-value format.

Example :- 'Time', 'P1','Q1','P2','Q2'....'P20','Q20' (total of 21columns)
P1,P2,...P20 can take various values ranging from 100..1000 I need to create a dataframe where values of P1..P20 becomes keys (key range from 100..1000) and corresponding values Q1,..Q20 should be each separate column. (Now you have 5mil columns)

It's like transpose of 1st dataframe (missing key values as 0).

Currently, I am converting each row in a dictionary with respective column values using df.ix[] and creating a dataframe of it and then joining.

```
for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    print(i)
    d = {'Price' : df.ix[:,list(range(2, 81, 2))].loc[i].values, 'Qty': df.ix[:,list(range(3, 82, 2))].loc[i].values}
    master1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
    master1.set_index('Price', inplace=True)
    master = master.join(master1, rsuffix=i)
```

For small amounts of data this is fine but on the 5 mil rows it takes far too much memory and time. Is there any way to make this faster?

```
EndGoal :- 
Current dataFrame Data :-
T1 P1 Q11 
T1 P2 Q21
T1 P3 Q31
T2 P1 Q12
T2 P2 Q22
T3 P3 Q32

Output :- 
P1 Q11 Q12
P2 Q21 Q22
P3 Q31 Q32
```

-Arpit

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Otherwise it's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It will be great a smaple of the original df and the expected output

Comment: The fastest way is to use Spark instead :D

Comment: What @rpanai meant is , could you post an example with say 5 rows, that shows what you are doing?

Comment: Could you provide more details in your question? Does each "P" column have only 1 associated "Q" column, like "P1" with "Q1" only?

Comment: Yes,  P1 has pnly Q1

Comment: How would that work in the final DataFrame? Row `P1` would have tons of values in the `Q1` column, and all the other ones will be empty? It might be worth taking a step back here and giving us some context. Why are you doing these operations? What is your goal? Can you show us some example data?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I have edited question with final endGoal.

Comment: @Arpit aaah I see. So it’s kind of like a merge and a transpose!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Can you please give an example,

Comment: @Arpit What kind of values can the "Qs" take?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, any integer.

Comment: @Arpit did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Nopes.. I have a solution but that is inefficient (takes very long time to complete)

Comment: @Arpit Can you share some test data, and more of your code? See [mcve].